# How to do post-build modifications in an Eclipse builder

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm currently working an Eclipse plug-in to provide iPOJO manipulation support.
The principle of iPOJO is to modify the .class files generated by the Java compiler to inject some methods and to add/update an entry to the Manifest.mf file.

Currently, my plug-in provides a project Nature and adds a Builder, added at the end of a project builder list, that calls the iPOJO Manipulator.
I use it on PDE projects.

The complete process works but I have a problem :

When my builder has finished its job (and the building process), the whole building process restarts, erasing the output folder and calling my builder again.
If I don't add a safety trick, it makes the building process loop over and over.

As I work on IResource, an IResourceDeltaEvent must be sent at the end of the building process, so I think the best way to avoid that kind of problem is to hide the fact that the resource has changed.

To be clear, I'm looking for a way to modify the class files after a PDE build, without inducing a new build, and without disabling the workspace auto-build property.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little unclear as to what you are describing.

You mention that you want this to work for PDE builds, but PDE builds happen largely outside of the workspace using ant scripts.  They do not use IResource, Builder, or IResourceDeltaEvent.

I am guessing that you don't really mean PDE builds, but rather the building of plugin projects inside of the workspace.

In general, Eclipse (JDT in particular) expects that it has complete control over the output folders.  However, there is an option in Preferences -> Java -> Building -> Output Folder called "Rebuild class files generated by others".  Ensure that this is disabled.  Eclipse should not try to rebuild class files that you touch.  If your builder only touches class files then it will not trigger other builds after it changes the class files.  The only thing is that you need to be careful not to compile things twice (and I think this is the problem that you are describing).

Alternatively, it may be easier for you to implement a CompilationParticipant (and the org.eclipse.jdt.core.compilationParticipant extension point).  This will allow you to know exactly when JDT calls a compilation and exactly what it compiles.

Additionally, you will be notified of reconcile operations (ie- changes in working copies that have not been saved).  This may be useful for you if you wanted to manipulate files as-you-type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer : my problem was the "Rebuild class..." option which was toggled on some of the compiled projects.
I've kept the Builder model for the moment, but CompilationParticipant seems interesting.